# Creating ViewControllers by swiping left programatically with new Data

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

There is a single **viewController** with some data in it. After swiping left or right I want to create new **viewControllers** having the same UI but having different data. What is the best method to do this ? Should I be using **UIPageViewController** ?

Comment: Exactly, `UIPageViewController` is a great way to solve your problem.

Comment: But all the examples given for UIPageViewController using storyboard have manually given all the viewControllers.

Comment: and you are downloading the data from somewhere? On swipe?

Comment: Nope, From Realm Database.

Comment: i will post a code only solution soon.

Comment: Thanks. For your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for **Swift 3** setting up a `UIPageViewController` programmatically.

The trick is to declare a `lazy array` called `pages` on your `UIPageViewController`.

In `viewDidLoad` using this `array` you can set up the viewControllers. Also, your `dataSource` is able to work with this array, handling the logic of changing the viewControllers. Right now, the `dataSource` is being implemented to continuously display the viewControllers, like a carousel. Modify it to your needs ;)

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

struct DisplayableData {
    let title: String
    let description: String
    // etc...
}

class DataViewController: UIViewController {
    var data: DisplayableData?
    // You can add data as an initalizer parameter, depending on your design needs
    init() {
        // If you would create a xib for your DataViewController, than replace nib name with DataViewController to make it work
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}

class PageViewController: UIPageViewController {

    lazy internal var pages: [DataViewController] = {
        // If the UI is the same, reuse the viewController, no need to create multiple ones
        // You could create a xib, and draw the UI there 
        let firstVC = DataViewController()
        // Assign your data structure to your viewController
        firstVC.data = DisplayableData(title: "first", description: "desc")

        let secondVC = DataViewController()
        secondVC.data = DisplayableData(title: "second", description: "desc")

        let thirdVC = DataViewController()
        thirdVC.data = DisplayableData(title: "third", description: "desc")

        return [firstVC, secondVC, thirdVC]
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataSource = self
        // Set your viewControllers
        setViewControllers([pages.first!], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension PageViewController: UIPageViewControllerDataSource {

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        // Lets check if the viewController is the right type
        guard let viewController = viewController as? DataViewController else {
            fatalError("Invalid viewController type in PageViewController")
        }

         // Load the next one, if it is the last, load the first one
        let presentedVCIndex: Int! = pages.index(of: viewController)
        if presentedVCIndex + 1 > pages.count - 1 {
            return pages.first
        }
        return pages[presentedVCIndex + 1]
    }

    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {

        // Lets check if the viewController is the right type
        guard let viewController = viewController as? DataViewController else {
            fatalError("Invalid viewController type in PageViewController")
        }

        // Load the previous one, if it is the first, load the last one
        let presentedVCIndex: Int! = pages.index(of: viewController)
        if presentedVCIndex - 1 < 0 {
            return pages.last
        }

        return pages[presentedVCIndex - 1]

    }

    func presentationCount(for pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int {
        return pages.count
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, will try to implement it. Merry Christmas !!